# CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost crashes unexpectedly with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cfstream

Finally time to ask my first question here!

Up front: Xcode 7.1.1, OS 10.11.2, iOS 9.0.2 (on physical device)

I'm writing a small app that communicates with my Raspberry Pi. I've got some working code that's written in Obj-C (for iOS 7) borrowed from a [tutorial](http://bitcows.com/?p=249), and it all works fine for me in Obj-C (connects and behaves as expected with the Pi). The issue lies with rewriting it for Swift/iOS 9 (which is the goal).

The good bit:

```
func initNetworkCommunication() {
    var readStream: Unmanaged<CFReadStreamRef>?
    var writeStream: Unmanaged<CFWriteStreamRef>?

    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(nil, "192.168.1.22", 777, &readStream, &writeStream)

    inputStream = readStream?.takeRetainedValue() as! NSInputStream
    outputStream = writeStream?.takeRetainedValue() as! NSOutputStream

    inputStream.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
    outputStream.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

    inputStream.open()
    outputStream.open()
}
```

I believe the issue to lie in the above as this is the last method call in the stack, however the application crashes quietly with little information:

[image: Crash Screen]

Any help would be much appreciated!
Please feel free to ask for more information.

p.s. I understand the formatting on this site is rather "strict", anything I missed, overdid, etc, please let me know :)

Comment: It didn't crash. It stopped at a breakpoint. Check your Breakpoint Navigator (`Cmd + 7`)

Comment: I noticed that. Didn't have any in the project (also note that they were disabled in the debug view). Regardless the changes I made below solved any of the issues. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've solved it.

Firstly:

```
inputStream = readStream?.takeRetainedValue() as! NSInputStream
outputStream = writeStream?.takeRetainedValue() as! NSOutputStream
```

Should be:

```
inputStream = readStream!.takeRetainedValue()
outputStream = writeStream!.takeRetainedValue()
```

Secondly, I abstracted the connection out of the ViewController (where I had this method initially) to a new class called Connection.

Here's Connection:

```
import UIKit

class Connection: NSObject, NSStreamDelegate {
    var inputStream: NSInputStream!
    var outputStream: NSOutputStream!

    func connect() {
        var readStream:  Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
        var writeStream: Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?

        CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(nil, "192.168.1.22", 777, &readStream, &writeStream)

        self.inputStream = readStream!.takeRetainedValue()
        self.outputStream = writeStream!.takeRetainedValue()

        self.inputStream.delegate = self
        self.outputStream.delegate = self

        self.inputStream.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
        self.outputStream.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

        self.inputStream.open()
        self.outputStream.open()
    }
}
```

Often I find starting to type these helps me out :p

Comment: Program hanged on this line

self.inputStream = readStream!.takeRetainedValue()

Comment: Wow, bit late to the party. I'd forgotten about this post entirely until now! Sadly to say I've got what I needed out of the project and don't have the code anymore. I can try and help diagnose the issue though if you need it, but I'll need a little more to go on than "it crashed."

Comment: Good one, :) like the answer